# Mercurial - How to revert merge, update

Tags: merge, mercurial

There was a file on a local machine, let's call it test.xml. It had been cloned and then edited on that local machine. These changes were not committed. Then, there was a pull, merge and update, which overwrote the local changes and replaced the file with the version on the default branch. Is there a way to revert these changes back to the local version? Since the local changes were not committed, there isn't a commit that can just be cloned or pulled from, it needs to go back to the local version before the pull.

Is this possible? I assume during the merge the local version was stored in some way...

Comment: local changes are not overwritten on pull, but the current working copy is merged with an update. So is your current state a merge of the changes with the newly-pulled version? Then simply update the working dir to the previous version and it will merge the uncommitted changes with that again

Comment: Right, the current state is a merge of the local, uncommitted changes with the newly-pulled version. The local changes were not included in the merge and I wish to have them back. 

You mention update to the previous version, how would I do that? This machine had not been updated since 2015 and there were many local changes that were overwritten by the merge. Should I update -r REV where REV is the previous version back in 2015? Will that prompt a merge including the local changes?

I am inexperienced with Mercurial and am hesitant to do something that could lose the local changes.

Comment: oh my... FIRST: Make a backup of the whole repository, including working dir. SECOND: update to the revision you previously used: hg up --rev REV. That should prompt a merge of the current working dir state (thus anything which is not committed) with that revision from back then. If there currently is nothing uncommitted in the working dir anymore: then it's tough luck. Note: a VCS does NOT replace a backup solution.

Comment: Understood. Just so I'm clear... say you are on default and make some changes on local machine. You don't commit the changes. Then you pull and merge, causing a diff between the local and remote versions. In the merge you remove all the local changes, leaving yourself with the remote version. Then you update. Is there no way to get those local changes back? I believe this is what happened on the machine.